# map parameter/argument bugging out(solution found)

Tags: c++, function, vector, dictionary

**Solution on bottom of this post**
I have this code:

```
void showMenu()
{
    const vector<string> vMainOptions { "Show List",
                                        "Enter new name" };

    map<int, string> mMainOptions = vectorToMap(vMainOptions);

    map<int, string>::const_iterator mIt = mMainOptions.begin();

    while(mIt != mMainOptions.end())
    {
        cout << mIt->first << ". " << mIt->second << endl;
        mIt++;
    }
}

map vectorToMap(const vector<string> myVector)
{
    vector<string>::const_iterator vIt = myVector.begin();
    map<int, string> myMap;
    while(vIt != myVector.end())
    {
        static int nr = 1;
        myMap->insert(make_pair(nr, *vIt));
        vIt++;
        nr++;
    }
    return myMap;
}
```

but it gives me these errors:

```
line 19: error: invalid use of template-name 'std::map' without an argument list
```

this is line 19:

```
map vectorToMap(const vector<string> myVector);
```

I did my best and tried many methods to fix that but it doesnt be OK.
It worked great before when all was in one function, but then i cant reuse that so i want to make a new function for that!(sorry if its short text but i just real need help)

**SOLUTION:**

```
void showMenu()
{
    const vector<string> vMainOptions { "Show List",
                                        "Enter new name"};

    map<int, string> mMainOptions = vectorToMap(vMainOptions);

    map<int, string>::const_iterator mIt = mMainOptions.begin();

    while(mIt != mMainOptions.end())
    {
        cout << mIt->first << ". " << mIt->second << endl;
        mIt++;
    }
}

map<int, string> vectorToMap(const vector<string>& myVector)
{
    vector<string>::const_iterator vIt = myVector.begin();
    map<int, string> myMap;
    while(vIt != myVector.end())
    {
        static int nr = 1;
        myMap.insert(make_pair(nr, *vIt));
        vIt++;
        nr++;
    }
    return myMap;
}
```

Comment: You're assigning a map to a void type function (vectorToMap). mMainOptions can't be assigned to a void type. And vectorToMap doesn't return anything. You're also using mMainOptions inside the vectorToMap function before it's been fully declared.

Comment: I suggest you say: map<int, string> mMainOptions;   And then call           vectorToMap(vMainOptions, mMainOptions);

Comment: Unrelated: I'm fairly sure you don't want to make a copy of that vector just to copy *that* into a map. Perhaps send it by const-reference instead of a rather pointless const-copy.

Comment: Was one of you many-tried methods to declare your function properly, i.e. `map<int, string> vectorToMap(const vector<string>& myVector)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` is a template rather than a valid type. You can not regard `map` as a general version of `map<int, string>`. Only the one with argument list can be used like a type. So: 
`map<int, string> vectorToMap(const vector<string> myVector);`
shall be fine. 
Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

VectorToMap needs to be of type: map mMainOptions, not of type void.
It needs a return statement to return the map it creates.

and you need either a forward declaration, or to move vectorToMap above showMenu, in the code.

Comment: I have a forward declaration. I tried to do it type map before but then it gave even more errors.. but can anybody say how do i create a map function that works?